# How to get file MFT entry/inode using Java or C++

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, hardlink, ntfs-mft

I've written a duplicate finder in Java, but I need to include hard link support for it. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to dig out a file's MFT entry in Java.

Although there is a method called fileKey() in the BasicFileAttributeView class, it won't work on the NTFS file system (I haven't tested it on ext yet).

I also found the method [isSameFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile) (in java.nio.file.Path). Does anyone know how this method works? It seems to be doing the right thing, but it returns a Boolean value, so it is worthless for me (I wish to put the results into a map and group them by their MFT entries).

I can always compare the creation times, modification times, etc. for each file, but this is just giving up.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do in either C++ or Java? I care more about making it work on NTFS than ext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [`FILE_ID_FULL_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540310.aspx) structure along with the [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047.aspx) function (or the [`FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540318.aspx) structure along with the [`NtQueryInformationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567052.aspx), if you already have a handle) inside `ntdll.dll` (available since Windows XP, if not earlier) to get the 8-byte file IDs and check if they are the same.

This will tell you if they are the same *file*, but not if they are the same *stream* of the same file.

I'm not sure how to detect if two files are the same stream from user-mode -- there is a structure named [`FILE_STREAM_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540364.aspx) which can return all the streams associated with a file, but it doesn't tell you *which* stream you have currently opened.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting hard links is usually accomplished by calling [`FindFirstFileNameW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364421.aspx).  But there is a lower level way.

To get the NTFS equivalent to inodes, try the [`FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364570.aspx) ioctl code.

There's a unique (until the file is deleted) identifier in the [`BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363788.aspx) as well.

If the volume has an enabled USN Change Journal, you can issue the [`FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364584.aspx) ioctl code.  Check the `FileReferenceNumber` member in the [`USN_RECORD` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365722.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use `sun.nio.ch.FileKey` which is a non-transparent enclosure for NTFS Inode. All the hard links share the same Inode.

Therefore, if you need to collect hard links, you can create `FileKey` from each suspect and compare them (e.g. by putting pairs of FileKey -> File into a `Multimap`)

Answer (score 0):

I find `fileKey` is always null.  Here is some code that can actually read the NTFS inode number.  There remain many aspects I'm not happy with, not least, it relies on reflection.

```
import sun.nio.ch.FileKey;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.file.Path;

class NTFS {
    static long inodeFromPath(Path path) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())) {
            FileDescriptor fd = fi.getFD();

            FileKey fk = FileKey.create(fd);
            Field privateField = FileKey.class.getDeclaredField("nFileIndexHigh");
            privateField.setAccessible(true);
            long high = (long) privateField.get(fk);
            privateField = FileKey.class.getDeclaredField("nFileIndexLow");
            privateField.setAccessible(true);
            long low = (long) privateField.get(fk);

            long power = (long) 1 << 32;
            long inode = high * power + low;
            return inode;
        }
    }
}
```